# Render scripts conditionally with routes in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm newbie to Angular, I want to know if there is any method to render scripts (CSS/JS) if ngRoute is equal to something. For example, I have following routes defined:

```
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'views/index.html',
            controller  : 'ProductsController'
        })
        // route for the contactus page
        .when('/admin', {
            templateUrl : 'admin/index.html',
            controller  : 'AdminController',

        })
```

and I want to render `<link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">` in the head when route is `"/"` and `<link href="css/admin.css" rel="stylesheet">` when route is `"/admin"` .

Comment: no, this isn't a supported option.

Comment: You could use something like [this library](https://github.com/GabrielDelepine/angular-css-injector), which provides a service for editing the stylesheets included in the page, and have your controllers manage those files depending on the context.

Comment: try to use required.js. It loads js and CSS with AMD mode. It's very good for loading js and CSS asynchronously, lazy loading or on demand loading, Dependency management, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, don't know whether it's proper or not, since it's rendering stylesheets after `</head>` but that solved my problem. What I did is, I defined a `MainController` as:

```
 myApp.controller('MainController', ['$scope','$location', '$routeParams', function($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
   if($location.path() == '/admin') {
        $scope.isAdmin = true;
   }
   else {
        $scope.isAdmin = false;
   }

  }]);
```

After that, instead of placing stylesheets inside `</head>`, I just placed a directive with the MainController and wrapped stylesheets in it after the head:

```
<div ng-controller="MainController">

    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet" ng-if="!isAdmin">

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` you can put:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href={{selectedType}}>
```

In the main controller you can put the condition if isAdmin

```
$rootScope.selectedType = isAdmin ? "css/admin.css" : "css/app.css"
```

Just make sure the `ng-app` is in your html: `<html ng-app="myApp">`